# Can we make the compound word filter not divide some words in solr?

Tags: solr, filter

I am using a ***DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilterFactory***. I have a **dutch compound_words_dict_nl.txt** which contains the following words:
**pen

slot

knop**

I use this dictionary to divide the words **penslot** and **knoppen**.

The problem is, I don't want the knoppen word considered as a compound word. It is a plural from knop. The filter will devide it to knop and pen, which will return results with knop and pen in them. But the knoppen word shouldn't generate a pen word. Just a stemmed version - knop (that I cover with a stemming filter in the analyzer).

If I take away the pen word from the dictionary, it will add only the word slot as a token, which I don't want for a penslot case.

**Is there an easy workaround for this type of issue or do I need to create some custom Filter?**

Comment: NGrams? Simplified and inaccurate: "knop pen" will reduce to "kn op kno nop pe en pen" and "knoppen" to "kn op kno nop pp pe ppe en pen" (notice only a few extra terms?) and they are searched and scored in the same way as stemmed terms.

Comment: @aitchnyu NGrams filter will create a huge index. If we want also words searched by whole word the index is going to be even bigger (=>ngrams size bigger => index bigger). I am just looking for a way for the compound word filter to accept exceptions. There should be a possibility like this since there is a valid use-case. Thanks for the proposal anyway!

Comment: @aitchnyu also NGrams filter will lead to the same issue - the word "knoppen" will return results that include "pen".

Comment: Of course it will. Maybe some dismax rules can eliminate totally irrelevant results based on the fraction of terms that match. I  had an interest as my language (Malayalam, in Kerala, India) also has even more complex compound words and as I learned that NGram was suitable for Asian languages.

Comment: I guess you can find natural language components like stemmers for Dutch. I guess the
'pen' in 'knoppen' is a suffix like 'ing' in 'eating'?

Comment: Exactly, "en" is a suffix for plural form. The issue is that the word gets split in two "knop" and "pen" before it is stemmed, but it shouldn't because its not a compound word. Anyway glad that you researched the same subject for your language. I intend to create a custom compound word filter which will support words that represent exceptions to the compound word filter: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3574. Once (if :) ) I do it, you can try it on your language and tell me what the performance difference is. Cheers!

Comment: @despot could you share your compound_words_dict_nl.txt with us?